# The incorrect tag description of [pochhammer-symbol]

Tags: discussion, tag-management

[The tag description](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pochhammer-symbol):

> The Pochhammer symbol is the notation used for rising and falling factorials. The $q$-Pochhammer symbol is the $q$-analog.

To be a $q$-analog, the $q$-Pochhammer symbol must equal the original expression (rising or falling factorial) as $q \rightarrow 1$ (or at least $q \rightarrow 1^-$). This is not the case, as is very easy to check. Details in my earlier question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3330984/why-is-the-q-pochhammer-symbol-referred-to-as-such-despite-not-being-a-q-anal). As I point out there, Wolfram MathWorld and Wikipedia both commit the same error. I'm not sure what the description should be instead, but we can't just have false statements lying around.

Comment: Note the Wikipedia article on [*q*-analog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q-analog) which explains: "q-analogues are most frequently studied in the mathematical fields of combinatorics and special functions. In these settings, the limit q → 1 is often formal, as q is often discrete-valued (for example, it may represent a prime power)."

Comment: Yet nowhere does it say that the limit criterion is not necessary for something to be a $q$-analog.

Comment: As you've posted a Question on the main Math.SE site about the justification for the terminology (or lack thereof), I'll try to address your presumed lack of justification there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've edited the tag info for [pochhammer-symbol](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pochhammer-symbol) to avoid the problematic claim that $q$-Pochhammer symbol is a $q$-analog of the Pochhammer symbol.

I'll post a discussion of the history of this "convention" on the [Main Math.SE Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3330984/why-is-the-q-pochhammer-symbol-referred-to-as-such-despite-not-being-a-q-anal), including a link to [a previous Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1868523/q-shifted-factorials) there that discusses the infelicity of such terminology.